# Solve for $y' + Py = ae^{bt}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve $y' + Py = ae^{bt}$?

My attempt: $y' + Py = ae^{bt}\Rightarrow Py - ae^{bt} + 1.\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}=0$, where $M(t,y)=Py - ae^{bt}$ and $N(t,y)=1$.

$M_{y}=P$, and $N_{t}=0$.

So the solution is not exact. How do I proceed from here?

**Edit:** Suppose $\mu (t)$ be the integrating factor.

Multiply both sides of the D.E. by $\mu (t)$ to obtain $$\mu (t)(Py - ae^{bt} + \mu (t)\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}=0$$.

Now, suppose $M_{y}=N_{t}$ so that $\mu (t)P = \mu '(t)$.

Solve to obtain $\mu (t)= e^{Pt}$.

Now multiply both sides of the D.E. by the integrating factor to obtain $$e^{Pt}(Py - ae^{bt} + e^{Pt}\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t}=0$$.

Now we have an exact D.E. since $M_{y}=e^{Pt}P=N_{t}$.

So $\Psi _{t} = e^{Pt}(Py - ae^{bt})$ and $\Psi _{y} = e^{Pt}$.

Hence, we obtain the solution: $\Psi = e^{Pt}y - \frac{a e^{Pt}e^{bt}}{P}+\frac{ae^{Pt}e^{bt}}{b}=C$.

Does this look correct?

Comment: You can use an integrating factor, no? It would seem to be easier.

Comment: haven't learned it yet. but will take a look.

Comment: Would you like me to make a post to show you how (I won't give you the full solution, just help so you can do it yourself).. Otherwise, tell us what method you want to use and we can go through that.

Comment: Not yet. I'll learn it and make an edit. Thanks.

Comment: Does it look right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're doing to be honest. I'm not sure why you keep setting things like $M_y = e^{Pt}$ and so on.. You'll need to explain what method you are using or what you have learnt in class so I can help you. Also, you have $\frac{dy}{dy}$ everywhere, when it should be $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: I used the method showed in Khan Academy's D.E. videos for integrating factors. Can you please post your solution so I can compare?

Comment: Sure, I'll put it up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$y' + Py = ae^{bt}$$

If we multiply both sides of this equation by $e^{Pt}$ we get

$$\begin{align}
e^{Pt}y' + Pe^{Pt}y &= ae^{bt}e^{Pt} \\
&= ae^{(P + b)t} \ \ \ (1) \\
\end{align}$$

Now remember the product rule? It states that

$$(x(t)y)' = x(t)y' + x'(t)y$$

which looks alot like the left hand side of our equation at $(1)$, where

$$x(t) = e^{Pt} \implies x'(t) = Pe^{Pt}$$

So we can now write $(1)$ as

$$\begin{align}
(e^{Pt}y)' &= \frac{d}{dt} \big(e^{Pt}y \big) \\
&= ae^{(P + b)t} \\
\end{align} $$

If we integrate both sides with respect to $t$ we find

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{d}{dt} \big(e^{Pt}y \big) dt &= \int ae^{(P + b)t} dt \\
\implies e^{Pt}y &= \frac{ae^{(P + b)t}}{P + b} \\
\end{align}$$

We can divide both sides by $e^{Pt}$, giving

$$\begin{align}
y &= e^{-Pt} \bigg(\frac{ae^{(P + b)t}}{P + b} \bigg) \\
&= \frac{ae^{bt}}{P + b}
\end{align}$$

You can check by differentiation that this is the solution.

(If you're wondering how we knew to choose $x(t) = e^{Pt}$, just write a comment below and I'll edit my solution to include the idea behind integrating factors. But I'm assuming, since you watched the Khan Academy videos, that you have some sort of understanding as to where it came from so I didn't want to repeat things you've already done).

**EDIT**

Suppose we have a linear differential equation of the form

$$y' + p(t)y = q(t) \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

(this is in the form your question is in, with $p(t) = P$ and $q(t) = ae^{bt}$). If we multiply $(*)$ by a function $r(t)$ we get

$$r(t)y' + r(t)p(t)y = r(t)q(t) \ \ \ \ (**)$$

What we want to do is *find a solution to $r(t)$ such that we can put the left hand side of $(**)$ in the form*

$$(r(t)y)'$$

so our equation becomes

$$(r(t)y)' = r(t)q(t)$$

But we know from the product rule that

$$(r(t)y)' = r(t)y' + r'(t)y \ \ \ \ \ (***)$$

Equating the left hand side of $(**)$ with $(***)$ we can see that we need to solve the equation

$$r'(t) = r(t)p(t)$$

which is just a standard ODE. Separating variables and integrating, we find

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{dr}{r(t)} &= \int p(t) dt \\
\implies \ln(r(t)) &= \int p(t) dt \\
\implies r(t) &= \exp \bigg(\int p(t) dt \bigg) \\
\end{align}$$

So our integrating factor is given by

$$r(t) = \exp \bigg(\int p(t) dt \bigg)$$

In your particular problem, $p(t) = P$, hence

$$\begin{align}
r(t) &= \exp \bigg(\int P dt \bigg) \\
&= \exp(Pt) \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Can I see how you found the integrating factor?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit it now.

Comment: Just one question: why is $\int \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} (e^{Pt}y) dt = e^{Pt}y$?

Comment: The derivative of an integral with respect to the same variable is just the function being evaluated (it's the fundamental theorem of calculus). Think about it.. if you integrate a function and then differentiate it straight away, shouldn't you end up with the same function you started off with in your integral?

Answer (score 1):

Find the integrating factor $\mu(t)=e^{\int p\;dt} = e^{\;pt}$

Now multiply the original differential equation by $\mu(t)$:

$$
e^{\;pt} y' + pe^{\;pt}y = ae^{\;bt}e^{\;pt}
$$

Noticing that the left side can be expressed as   $(e^{\;pt}y)'$, thus we can integrate both sides.  The next few steps aren't too bad.  The integrating factor method is pretty awesome!