# How can I prove that a PDE's solution is greater than $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have this PDE system:

$\frac{d}{dt}x(r,t)=-\int_{[0,1]}J(|r-r'|)y(r',t)dr'x(r,t)$

$\frac{d}{dt}y(r,t)=\int_{[0,1]}J(|r-r'|)y(r',t)dr'x(r,t)-y(r,t)$

$x(r,0)=a(r), y(r,0)=1-a(r)$

where $J:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R^+}$ is smooth and $a(r)\in (0,1)$ for all $r$.

I want to prove that the solutions $x(r,t)$ and $y(r,t)$ are greater (or equal) than $0$ for every $r\in [0,1]$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Since 
$x(r,t)=a(r)e^{-\int_0^t\int_0^1 J(|r-r'|)y(r',t)dr'}$

I have that $x(r,t)>0$, but how can I prove that $y(r,t)\geq 0$?
Thanks

EDIT

If I understood well I have

$y(r,t)=e^{-t}\int_0^tdt'e^{t'}\int_0^1J(|r-r'|)y(r',t)dr'x(r, t')+1-a(r)$

I know that $x(r,t)>0$, $1-a(r)>0$ but how can I conclude that
$y(r,t)\geq 0$?

Thank you very much

Comment: For the $y(r,t)$ equation, why not use an integrating factor.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer... sorry but what do you mean with integrating factor? Thank you again

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126032/solve-for-y-py-aebt/1126694#1126694).

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I tried to use an integrating factor. I wrote what I did in the question but I'm not sure that it is correct. Could you take a look at it? Thank you very much.